# Problem with box edges

Tags: tables, framed

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.0}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
    {\begin{tabular}{c|l|l|l|l|l|l|c}
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Active} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Passive} &  \\
            \cmidrule{2-7}        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[4]{*}{Asset Allocation}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{IV Actual Portfolio Returns}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{II Policy and active asset Allocation Return}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Active} \\
            & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} &  \\
            \cmidrule{2-7}             & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{III Policy and Security  Selection Returns}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{I Policy Returns (Passive Portfolio Benchmark)}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Passive} \\
            & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} &  \\
            \cmidrule{2-7}    
\end{tabular}}%
\caption{Security Selection}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  But what are you asking?  You've given us a blob of code that may or may not do something; and it's not formatted as code (indent it with four spaces, or highlight it and use the `{}` button).  Also, provide a minimal working example, to make it easier to help you.

Comment: applying `\resizebox` to tables (or any text) should only be done as an absolute last resort, it guarantees inconsistent fonts and rule widths.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the "Problem with box edges"  refers to the missing connection between the horizontal and vertical lines that is highlighted with the red circles in the following screenshot:

[image]

This is caused by you combining `\cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package with  vertical lines. As the `booktabs` documentation states, its horizontal lines are not intended to be used in combination with vertical lines resulting in the observed gaps. To overcome this, you can simply replace all `\cmidrule` commands with `\cline`.

However, I'd also recommend some more simplifications to your code. These are shown in the following MWE and include:

- replacing `adjustbox` (not recommended since it leads to inconsistent and too small font sizes)  with `tabularx` to make sure the table fits into the text width.
- removing redundant column. Your table only needs 4 columns not 7.
- adding `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to vertically center the text
- using `cellspace` instead of combining `arraystretch` with empty rows in order to add more vertical white space above and below the cells
- ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{20pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|X|X|Sc}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Active} 
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Passive}   \\
    \cline{2-3}        
    \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell[r]{Asset\\ Allocation}} 
        & IV Actual Portfolio Returns 
             & II Policy and active asset Allocation Return 
                 & Active \\
    \cline{2-3}
        & III Policy and Security  Selection Returns 
            & I Policy Returns (Passive Portfolio Benchmark) 
                & Passive \\
    \cline{2-3}    
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Security Selection}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```